GNU date - parsing timezone with +HH:MM format
I'm trying to parse a date that's extracted via exiftool from the metadata of MOV files. It comes in a format of e.g. 2024:05:31 20:57:23+03:00. Even though GNU's date has the %:z option, and it is able to produce a timestamp in such format, it's unable to parse existing value of it:
# echo $creation_date
2024:05:31 20:57:23+03:00

# date "+%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S%:z"
2024:06:08 22:04:15+02:00

# date "+%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S%:z" -d "$creation_date"
date: invalid date ‘2024:05:31 20:57:23+03:00’

What am I missing here?

Is timezone the problem? Year month day is separated by :

date != strptime(). The format string for date is functionally the same as for strftime(), i.e. it's the output format you want, not an input format that you want it to parse as it would be if you used a tool that has a strptime() function. date expects the input to be in some common date/time format, none of which have :s in the date.

exiftool has a -d option

You can use exiftool's -d (-dateFormat) option to reformat the date/time to use hyphens rather than colons.

Timezone is not a problem. Year-month-day is separated with :, which is unusual. They can be separated with - for date to understand them. See "DATE STRING" section in man date. You could change them:
creation_date='2024:05:31 20:57:23+03:00'
read -r ymd rest <<<"$creation_date"
date -d "${ymd//:/-} $rest"

Use strptime command from dateutils if you want to give exact format specification.

Using colons to separate Year:Month:Date is the format specified by the EXIF standard, Exiftool uses this across all Date/Time tags for simplicity's sake.
